# subcat for url with .htaccess and php

Tags: php, jquery, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

I used this [project](https://management-menu.herokuapp.com). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqyrJ.png)

This is my SQL (**phpmyadmin**):

```
-----------------------------------------------
| id |   label   |   link  |  parent  | sort | 
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  |     A     |    a    |    0     |  1   |
| 2  |     B     |    b    |    1     |  2   |
| 3  |     C     |    c    |    1     |  3   |
| 4  |     D     |    d    |    0     |  4   |
| 5  |     E     |    e    |    2     |  5   |
| 6  |     F     |    f    |    3     |  6   |
| 7  |     G     |    g    |    0     |  7   |
-----------------------------------------------
```

this is my **urls**:

```
example.com/index.php?link=a
example.com/index.php?link=a/b
example.com/index.php?link=a/b/e
example.com/index.php?link=a/c
example.com/index.php?link=a/c/f
example.com/index.php?link=d
example.com/index.php?link=g

to

example.com/a
example.com/a/b
example.com/a/b/e
example.com/a/c
example.com/a/c/f
example.com/d
example.com/g
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ index.php?link=$1
```

this is my **php**:

```
if(!empty($_GET['link'])){
 $url=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['link']);
 $query="SELECT * FROM menu WHERE link='$url'"; 
 $result=mysqli_query($db,$query);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['id'];
 }   
}
```

When I run the link `http://example.com/d/` in the browser address bar, Its output is as follows:
`4`.

But when I run the link `http://example.com/a/b/e`, Its screen turns white or that output does not show.

Comment: You are rewriting this to `index.php?link=a/b/e`, and then you go look into your database for a record where the `link` column has the value `a/b/e`. Of which there simply _are none_ (according to the DB contents you have shown), so I am not sure what you expected to happen here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting this to **index.php?link=a/b/e**

Comment: I think you should credit the comment. And maybe do more of an explanation.